# ASP.NET Core exclude property of viewmodel when submitting form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a controller/action/view which contains a form to generate reports.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Report(int? entityId, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
}
```

On HTTP GET, I first check if `entityId` is empty. If it is, I assume the user is navigating to `/report/` to populate the form fields to generate a report, so I just return a partial viewmodel containing information about dropdowns, etc:

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
    // ...

    // this is populated as user has to choose one of these via dropdown
    // to generate a report.  
    public IEnumerable<EntityAccountDTO> EntityAccounts { get; set; }

    // ... other properties left unpopulated at this point
}
```

Choosing an `EntityAccounts` option from the dropdown populates two date pickers with values that will be used for `fromDate` and `toDate` in the `/report/` action parameters. This does not need to be sent back to the GET action when generating the report.

The form in the view is then populated and the user clicks on "Get Report". At this point the same GET action is hit, but `entityId.HasValue` is `true`, `fromDate` and `toDate` have values from the dropdowns, so I have all the info to generate the report. I then generate a full viewmodel and return it back to the same view.

Some problems I see:

Dropdown of `EntityAccounts` is submitted back to the action (I can see it in the query string). As mentioned before this is only there for the user to initially select a value, I don't need it submitted back to the action.. How do I prevent it from being submitted?

```
    <label asp-for="@Model.EntityAccounts">Entity accounts</label>
    <!-- Input -->
    <select asp-for="@Model.EntityAccounts" class="form-control" data-toggle="select">
        @foreach () { //... generate <option>s }                           
    </select>
```

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Do you mean you did not want `@Model.EntityAccounts` to append to the query string? If so, how server side use it?

Comment: Hi, server side does not use it, it just returns it the first time to populate a dropdown (but once the dropdown is populated, I don't need the value to be returned back to the server)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [[BindNever]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#bindnever-attribute) attribute on your view model property to prevent the model binder from setting it.

```
[BindNever]
public IEnumerable<EntityAccountDTO> EntityAccounts { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks, will client validation still occur if I add to it `BindNever` and `Required` for example?

Comment: @globetrotter yes you can still do validation on the model. Setting a property to BindNever doesn't invalidate the model state; it just ignores that property. But if you mean setting BindNever and Required on the same property, I'm not sure why you'd want to do that? I would not expect that to pass validation.

Comment: What I mean is, the user *should* choose an `EntityAccountDTO` from the `EntityAccounts` dropdown when submitting the form. So client validation should say "`EntityAccount` is required" (if user hasn't selected an option from the dropdown) but *not submitted* with the form back to the server. I might have structured this action/view completely wrong, having one GET action accomodating all of this..